# Can Ryougi Shiki see "Death" in inanimate objects?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners, tsukihime

In Tsukihime, Tohno Shiki is able to see "death" with his Mystic Eyes of Death Perception in not just living things but in objects as well. Aoko explains to him that all objects, both living and inanimate, inherently have "death" when they are created. In parts of Tsukihime it's shown that Tohno Shiki can cut these lines of "death" to destroy objects. For example, when he fights Roa at the school in the Arcuied Route/Anime he destroys an entire hall with just his knife.

Ryougi Shiki, after she woke up from her coma as obtained the Mystic Eyes of Death Perception. However we only ever see her use it on living things or things that were once alive (like the Ghosts that were with Kirie Fujou or her Ghost Body, the Corpse the Wraiths possessed, or the Wraiths themselves when they were in Ryougi Shiki). The only time we ever see her "cut" anything which wasn't alive is when she fights Fujino Asagami and "cuts" the incoming use of her Mystic Eyes of Distortion or when she cuts Souren Araya's Rokudou Kyoukai. However these are more "conceptual things" rather than "inanimate things".

Tohno Shiki's Mystic Eyes of Death Perception were essentially broken because he couldn't turn them off and had to use Touko's Mystic Eye Killers, which Aoko had stolen. He also gets headaches when he isn't wearing the Mystic Eye Killers or when he tries to understand the Existence of Inanimate Objects (the dot where the lines of death meet), the latter causing even worse headaches. Ryougi Shiki's however seem to be normal. Touko ends up teaching her how to turn them off (they were always on when she woke up in The Hollow Shrine, turned off temporarily when she damaged her eyes but by Overlooking the Scenery she could turn them on and off at will) and would have told her about seeing death in other things explaining her ability to understand cutting Rokudou Kyoukai or Fujino's attack.

Can Ryougi Shiki see "death" in inanimate objects like Tohno Shiki can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "inanimate."

Generally, intangible objects like words cannot be "killed" because they do not exist. A phenomenon like a storm cannot be killed, but the particular event (rain/wind/clouds) can be dispersed.

In the *[Tsukihime Dokuhon Plus Period](http://www.tsukikan.com/tmdb/tsukihime-dokuhon-plus-period)* book, Nasu makes mention that:

> Ryougi's Shiki Mystic Eyes is superior to Tohno's. She (unlike Tohno) is able to perceive the death of just about anything, however she is limited to what she perceives as "alive."

So take something like a chair, which is seen as "alive," because it's not broken. Ryougi would see lines on a new chair, but not on a broken chair, because she believes that it is already "dead."

Note that this notion only applies to her perception of the "living" as opposed to if something "has life." Even though Kirie Fujou's ghosts were "dead," they could still be killed because they are "alive" in the sense that they could interact and interfere with the real world, as if they were alive.

As a side note, Araya's barrier is linked to his body, so when Ryougi cut it, it's like cutting a part of Araya (this is why he is in pain).